# Get data from a given ID

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller

I'm new to ASP.Net MVC. I'm trying to get hard coded data from an ID from a query string.

I'm developing a simple ASP.Net web project. There's customer data which are hard coded. I needed to retrieve and display data in another page when redirect by clicking a hyperlink.

//CustomerController

```
public ActionResult Details(int id) {


            var viewModel = new RandomMovieViewModel {
                CustomerID = id,
                CustomerName = "Test"
            };
            return View(viewModel);

        }
```

//RandomViewModel class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Vidly.Models;

namespace Vidly.ViewModels
{
    public class RandomMovieViewModel
    {
        public Movie Movie { get; set; }
        public List<Customer> Customers { get; set; }

        public List<Movie> Movies { get; set; }

        public int CustomerID { get; set; }

        public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

//Index.cshtml

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Customers</h2>
@if (Model.Customers.Count == 0)
{
    <text>We don't have any customers yet.</text>
}
else
{

    <ul class="list-group">
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <b>Customer</b>

        </li>

        @foreach (var customer in Model.Customers)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                <a href="../Customers/Details/@customer.Id">

                    @customer.Name
                </a>

            </li>
        }

    </ul>
}
```

Details.cshtml

```
@model Vidly.ViewModels.RandomMovieViewModel
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@Model.CustomerName</h2>
```

Should display the selected customer name when hyperlink clicked.

Comment: Where is  Customer Model? This problem is not clear I think.

Comment: And what happens currently when you click the hyperlink? It's unclear what the actual problem is

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach (var customer in Model.Customers)
    {
        <li class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <a href="../Customers/Details/@customer.Id">

                @customer.Name
            </a>

        </li>
    }
```

for getting id value from view in query string  you need to enhance your code with

```
 <a href="../Customers/Details?id=@customer.Id">
```

Comment: Thanks for help!!. I fixed this with a code modification in CustomersController. "CustomerName = customers.Where(x => x.Id == id).Select(x => x.Name).Single().ToString()" did the trick!! :)